# Typescript React - Redux - Actions not reaching reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux. I am trying to implement Redux in my React app, but the actions are for some reason not reaching my reducers. I am following these examples: https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo and https://codesandbox.io/s/w02m7jm3q7

For some reason I cannot get it working. This is my code:

## Redux:

**store/index.ts**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

import { sidebarReducer } from "./sidebar/reducers";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    sidebar: sidebarReducer
});

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export default function configureStore() {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());
    return store;
}
```

**store/sidebar/actions.ts**

```
import { sidebarState, TOGGLE_SIDEBAR } from "./types";

export function toggleSidebar() {
    console.log("hoi");
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_SIDEBAR,
        payload: {}
    }
}
```

**store/sidebar/reducers.ts**

```
import { TOGGLE_SIDEBAR, sidebarState, SidebarActionTypes } from "./types";

const initialState: sidebarState = {
    isOpen: false
}

export function sidebarReducer(state = initialState, action: SidebarActionTypes): sidebarState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: {
            console.log("Haai");
            return {
                ...state,
                isOpen: !state.isOpen
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**store/sidebar/types.ts**

```
export interface sidebarState {
    isOpen: boolean;
}

export const TOGGLE_SIDEBAR = "TOGGLE_SIDEBAR";

interface ToggleSidebarAction {
    type: typeof TOGGLE_SIDEBAR;
    payload: sidebarState;
}

export type SidebarActionTypes = ToggleSidebarAction;
```

## React:

**components/navbar/navbar.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './navbar.scss';
import '../../css/spacing.scss';
import { toggleSidebar } from '../../store/sidebar/actions'
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Navbar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
                <li className="nav-link sidebar-link" onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}>
                    <i className="fas fa-bars fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
                </li>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, toggleSidebar)(Navbar);
```

For some reason this is not working. When I click on the button it does arrive in the action, but it doesn't reach the reducer. I know I am not dispatching, but there is also no dispatching in the examples I am following. Both examples come from the docs, so it should be right. I have tried a lot of things and nothing was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your connect function to receive an object with action functions at second param:

```
export default connect(null, { toggleSidebar })(Navbar);
```

now, `connect` will take your action reducer and pass it to `dispatch` (responsible to call the reducers), creating a new function. you have access to this new function at your component through props, with same naming:

```
<li className="nav-link sidebar-link" onClick={ this.props.toggleSidebar }>
```